# Gantry Framework-Joomla How to edit logo from CSS

Tags: css, joomla3.0, joomla-template

I would like to know how can I edit CSS files(ex:Logo size, Logo path)
I am using  Grantry v4.1.24 and Joomla 3.3.1

See the example of how to change Logo;

```
#rt-logo {
background: url("/qatarclean/joomla_gantry/images/logo.png") no-repeat scroll 50% 0 transparent !important;
}

#rt-logo {
height: 140px;
width: 267px;
}
```

How can I find the CSS location for this and how to edit this?
in Firebug it is only showing the only the folder path.
I have created gantry-custom.css file and inserted above data. It doesn't work.

See the attached picture;
[image: FireBug Logo element]

Also I want to know how to remove some lines from selected CSS file;

Thanks in Advance,

**Sameera Silva**

Comment: This might get a better response over on http://joomla.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gantry Framework uses compiled LESS files. Rather than editing these directly, it is recommended (as you have done) that a custom CSS or custom LESS file is created so that your changes are not overwritten by a template update.

The use of `!important` might be the reason your override is not working.

You can get around this using CSS specificity as explained by Henning on the RocketTheme Forums at: http://www.rockettheme.com/forum/configuration-and-security/209832-want-nail-how-2use-template-name-custom-css-file-correctly#1028846

For more information on CSS specificity Henning recommends: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know

In this particular case, the following should fix the issue you are having:

```
div#rt-logo {
    background: url("/qatarclean/joomla-gantry/images/logodf.png") no-repeat scroll 50% 0 transparent !important;
}
```